# Magento 2 - On save user insert to other table on database

Tags: magento2, admin-user

I created a new tab on User edit, with a form

I want to save the data getting from the form the other table on Database (Ex: `test_table`) when I click on `save user` button, is there any method to do that?

[image: Button of user back-office Magento 2]

I try to use events

XML:

```
<event name="customer_account_edited">
    <observer name="test_event" instance="Testing\Test\Observer\TestUserOnSave"/>
</event>
```

PHP (TestUserOnSave)

```
public function execute(Observer $observer){
   $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logger.log');
   $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
   $logger->addWriter($writer);
   $logger->info('test events');
}
```

But it's doesn't work, is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create module with observer that will load for example on

' admin_user_save_after`  event

In observer you can insert Your function.

List of events:
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, but I don't find `admin_user_save_after` events (for admin-user, not the customer)

Comment: Oh sorry I edited answer

Comment: I try it, but it's doesn't work, I think this events `customer_account_edited` it's just for customers and not for admin users, you can check my new edit on the post

Comment: what about admin_user_save_after